# ZXING Intent integrator in a view

Tags: android, zxing

i have been tying to include the zxing library in my app by using the IntentIntegrator but what happens is it takes the user into a differnet acitvity how can i show the view of the zxing viewfinder in a view like framelayout i even tried the dm77 zxing but the problem with that was i wasn't able to get the image of the barcode scanned by using the zxing i'm unable to show it in my customview
any leads on how to do it..?

```
scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator((activity));
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });
```

how can show the integrator.initiateScan() in a view and change the orientation of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom view like [QRCodeReaderView](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView)

Comment: The library you mentioned doesn't give us the option to get the image of the barcode scanned right that was one of the keypoints im looking for